# Calculate the probability with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, statistics, probability, feature-engineering

I want to add an extra feature to my spark DataFrame, and this feature is a probability that represents (number of fails / total), this feature will give me an idea about how many fails there are. I want to know if there are other assumptions that I can use like using a statistic test or something like that to have more accurate calculations (scientifically correct)